# HttpClient postasync with custom header and application/json for body C#

Tags: c#, json, httpclient, json-serialization

Hello I want to run push app center from its `api`. But I don't know how to make the proper format.

I want to `postasync` from this api: https://appcenter.ms/api/v0.1/apps/KacangIjo/ShopDiaryApp/push/notifications

What it needs for Headers is:
X-API-Token ="{api token}" and Content Type="application/json"

For the body(content) I want to put this:

```
{
    "notification_content" : {
        "name" : "Campaign Name",
        "title" : "Expired Warning",
        "body" : "You have items that almost expired"
    }
}
```

I have difficulties how to write in the correct format for HttpClient.
I tried this and no work..

```
Content = new Content
{
   Name = "Campaign Name",
   Title = "Expired Warning",
   Body = "You have items that almost expired"
};
using (var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) })
{
   var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-Token", "{my api token}");
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
   MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   var builder = new UriBuilder(new Uri("https://appcenter.ms/api/v0.1/apps/KacangIjo/ShopDiaryApp/push/notifications"));
   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(builder.Uri, content);
};
```

But I know this code:

```
 {
        "notification_content" : {
            "name" : "Campaign Name",
            "title" : "Expired Warning",
            "body" : "You have items that almost expired"
        }
    }
```

is not same with this to convert the json format:

```
Content = new Content
{
    Name = "Campaign Name",
    Title = "Expired Warning",
    Body = "You have items that almost expired"
};
```

Can help me with the correct Serialize Json Format? and the correct format of httpclient header and body?
I already found lot of sample but still no clue with the one that I want.
Really appreciate your help guys :)

Comment: There are many articles available in the net, e.g. https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-named-typed-clients-aspnetcore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to structure your objects similar to your required `JSON`.

Create classes like below.

```
public class NotificationContent
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("body")]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class PostObject
{
    [JsonProperty("notification_content")]
    public NotificationContent NotificationContent { get; set; }
}
```

Above is the right structure, now when you will call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, your json will be

```
 {
    "notification_content" : {
        "name" : "Campaign Name",
        "title" : "Expired Warning",
        "body" : "You have items that almost expired"
    }
}
```

Below is the code for http call

```
using (var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) })
    {
        PostObject postObject = new PostObject
        {
            NotificationContent = new NotificationContent
            {
                Name = "Campaign Name",
                Title = "Expired Warning",
                Body = "You have items that almost expired"
            }
        };

        var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postObject);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-Token", "{my api token}");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var builder = new UriBuilder(new Uri("https://appcenter.ms/api/v0.1/apps/KacangIjo/ShopDiaryApp/push/notifications"));

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, builder.Uri);
        request.Content = new StringContent(myContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");//CONTENT-TYPE header

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :) this one really working. I working this things 3 days straight.. Thanks